# Как создать несколько окон в приложении?

Tags: java, swing, awt

По нажатии на кнопку хочу создать одно диалоговое окно. Вот код класса.

```
 package TextEditor;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GraphixWindow extends JDialog {
public  GraphixWindow (JFrame perent){
    this.setTitle("Построение графика");
    this.setSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    add(panel);
    this.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Вот сам вызов в другом классе внутри `ActionPerformed()`

```
if (e.getSource()==graphixButton){
GraphixWindow gw = new GraphixWindow(this);
gw.setVisible(true);
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку диалоговое окно не появляется. Не пойму, что я делаю не так. Вроде `setVisible (true);` и в конструкторе и в обработчике события есть. Как создать несколько окон в приложении?

В главном классе рисую много кнопок, вкладок и т.д Может в потоке проблема? Есть у кого хоть какие-то предположения? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GraphixWindow {

    public GraphixWindow() { // Публичный конструктор, куда передаем весь приватный метод
        init();
    }

    private void init() { // Приватный метод, где работаем с окном
        JDialog jDialog = new JDialog();
        jDialog.setTitle("Построение графика");
        jDialog.setSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        jDialog.add(panel);
        jDialog.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Я запустил окно в `Main`, ты можешь где угодно.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GraphixWindow graphixWindow = new GraphixWindow(); // Создал экземпляр класса
    }
}
```